# simple textbox validation in <rich:modalPanel> using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces

I have a  with a  textbox and   which submits the modalPanel.

On Click of the button, I want to check if the text box has been filled through a JavaScript Function.

Any suggestions..??

Here is the code:
*For the modalPanel--*

```
<h:form id="theForm">
<rich:modalPanel id="diskPanel" width="350" height="250">
<f:facet name="header">
    <h:panelGroup>
        <h:outputText value="Create New Disk"></h:outputText>
    </h:panelGroup>
</f:facet>
<h:panelGrid columns="2" width="70%">
    <h:outputLabel value="Disk Name* :" />
    <h:inputText value="#{myform.newDiskName}" id="diskPanel_diskName"/>

    <h:commandButton value="Create-Attach" id="submit_disk" 
           onclick="return validateDiskPanel()"
      action="#{myform.cloudButtonActionRequest('newdisk')}">
    <rich:componentControl for="diskPanel" attachTo="submit_disk"
    operation="hide" event="onclick" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:panelGrid>

</rich:modalPanel>
    </h:theForm>
```

*Code For the JavaScript Function---*

function validateDiskPanel(){  var obj1 = document.getElementById("theForm:diskPanel_diskName");  var obj2 = document.getElementById("theForm:diskPanel_diskSize");  if(obj1 == ""){  alert("Please provide Disk Name");  Richfaces.showModalPanel('diskPanel');  return false;  }  return true;  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<rich:ajaxValidator>`.
Here is the [example](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/ajaxValidator.jsf;jsessionid=CB09A94F21970AC6C7938A1490C095E5?c=ajaxValidator&tab=usage).

Else if you are rigid to use javascript validation then don't use `<rich:componentControl>` as the panel will hide on page reload for successful submission.

Answer (score 1):

The easier way to do this is using the `required` prop. and a `h:message` or `rich:message` (or h:messages / rich:messages for global messages) on your textbox.

Example:

```
<h:inputText label="Job" id="box" required="true" value="#{bean.prop}"/>
<rich:message for="box"/>
```

More especific example [here](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/message.jsf;jsessionid=FC10FC1314F53973CC55916108A2E22A?c=message&tab=usage).

If you dont want to use required, check options under Ajax Validators tab at the livedemo site, like rich:ajaxValidator as @niksvp said.